# Weak Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

I am studying a special type of a sequence on the naturals which I am calling a weak arithmetic progression.

Formally I call a k-sequence $x_1< x_2 \cdots< x_k$ a weak arithmetic progression (WAP) if $\exists d\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{i+1}-x_i\in\{1,d\}$. Now supposing all positive integers have been partitioned into two parts is there an upper bound on how many times a segment of $t$ consecutive numbers ($0\leq t\leq \frac{k-1}{2}$) in one part can occur without a WAP occurring in any one part?

Comment: Why can't I see the whole question? :S


Comment: When I click edit I can see the whole question but otherwise I am seeing only one & a half sentences. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: You have to leave a space after any < character, otherwise markdown will interpret it as a start of an HTML tag. Also, you need to double backslashes in commands like \{, \}, \\.

Comment: If neither of the two parts have a WAP of length k then neither have an AP of length k and so each part must have a piece of the integer interval (n , n+k]; it follows that this piece must often be an AP of length at least 2 and difference 1 infinitely many times.  I suspect one can avoid many, if not all, WAPs of bounded difference by using pieces of lengths 2 and 3, but it is clear that one needs infinitely many such pieces of each length.  Are you trying to bound t instead?  Gerhard "Ask Me Aboout System Design" Paseman. 2012.06.05 

Comment: Is WAP also known as "bounded gaps"?  If so, search that term for lots of info.

Comment: How does this relate to the question you asked at m.se, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153208/counting-number-of-k-sequences/153361

Comment: @Gerald, "bounded gaps" set is known as syndetic set, which corresponds to having $x_{i+1}−x_{i}\in \{1,\ldots,d\}$, which is a bit different than Shahab's question, but that might be a good direction... 

Comment: @Asaf: Yes. I searched for bounded gaps and came to the same conclusion.
@Gerry Myerson: There is no direct relation I believe. I thought this is significantly harder and more of a question suited for this site.

Comment: @Shahab, just some stupid thought, have you tried to start from syndetic sets (which I'm sure there's a lot of research about them, they are related to neighbrhoods of the unity in the Bohr compactification of the integers, and come up quite often in dynamics), and then try to filter them by using characters or something (a-la Dirichlet?).